# A curious property of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

The number $198$ has a curious property. If we factorise it as $198 = 2\times3^2\times11$ and factorise its "reverse" as $891 = 3^4\times11$ and sum up the numbers which appear in each factorisation:
$$
2+3+2+11 = 18 \quad\text{ and }\quad 3+4+11 = 18\;,
$$
we obtain the same number. Indeed, all of $18, 198, 1998, 19998, \dotsc$ have this property. Is there mention of such integers anywhere in the existing literature?

Comment: $19...98 = 18 * 11...1$, $89...91 = 81*11...1$, so it all comes to $2*3^2 \sim 3^4$ which is basically a coincidence. Note that you use $2$, not $2^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is known on [oeis](https://oeis.org/A086573).

In fact 19...98 are numbers of the form $18 * 111...11 $ while their reverses may be written $81 * 111...11 $

When you factorise them , you get on the 2 sides the $11....11$ which simplify whatever the operation is an addition or a product. Remain on a side $18$ and $81$ on the other. And these 2 entities have the trivial property to be such that $18 = 2 . 3^2$ and $81 = 3^4$ and $2 + 3 + 2 = 3 + 4$

As Abstraction wrote, if you want to hold the unity powers you must change the *remarkable* relation. Anyway, integers are fascinating.

That's all ...

Comment: Let n be a natural number. Denote by r(n) the "reverse" of n, by v(n) the sum of the numbers appearing in the canonical factorization of n (like before). Is the sequence of integers n s.t. v(n)=v(r(n)), n<r(n) and 10\nmid n also known in oeis?

Comment: @DanielChen-HsunTsai : what is 10 mid n ? note that to search on oeis you need only to submit a few nimbers of the sequence ( separated by spaces )

Comment: 10\nmid n means "n is not a multiple of 10".

Comment: the sequences are searchable by explicit values. I'll try to find such sequences after finding some elements

Comment: Let's call these numbers "remarkable numbers". Then the first few remarkable numbers are then 18, 198, 576, 819, 1131, 1304, 1818, 1998, 2262, 3393. I think this sequence is not known in oeis.

Comment: With a toy function in javascript to compute factorization, I found many others similar sequences with the simple model of the original : a repetition product a constant and the reverse checking : 2284848462, 4195959554 , 7090909020 , etc About oeis, it would be fine to explore other correlations because the missing power-1 in the rule of this question. The nine family in basis 10 seems prolific. Is it the case of every basis with the digit basis minus 1 ?

Comment: I think that there are no 2-digit "base 9 remarkable numbers".